# Android custom listview row with shape drawable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-drawable

I was following [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2012/02/06/androidndashcreate-a-listview-with-rounded-corners.aspx) tutorial and I've applied that code in my xml but round corner is on full listview not in particular row. And I did exactly like the tutorial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="true">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaPedidos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/background_pedidos"
        android:dividerHeight="7dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pedidos_shape"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

pedidos_shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/custom_gray" />
    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mistake:

You have given background to whole ListView.

### Resolution:

Background should be given it to individual items. Remove `android:background="@drawable/pedidos_shape"` from the `<ListView>` and include it inside the row XML layout file.

Answer (score 2):

set background item.xml(custom listview row xml)

custom_listview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/pedidos_shape">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there anything new in your answer other than mentioned in existing answers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `android:background="@drawable/pedidos_shape"`to the item layout that you are inflating in your adapter.